# how to do time over in games per socket in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I develop a Poker game using NodeJS in the server and HTML5 in the client.

All my core logic is in the server and not in the client. This is because the client can edit the javascript and change the logic of the game to his benefit.

I want to make a TimeOver function to the client. For example, if he doesnt play in 30 seconds, he will do a default action(check/fold).

My question is how to do it?
I cant do it in the javascript because the client can edit it.
And if i'll do it in the server, isn't it block the server?
I thought of openning a new thread for each socket, and do the timeout function there, but it'll be not efficient, what if i got like 10K sockets?

Comment: You should do both. The client gets 29 sec to play, with visual reminders. The server plays for the client after 30 sec, with a message to all players, incl the slow client. Timeouts won't block the server. With 10K sockets, it might be very inefficient, but let's think about that when you reach 2K.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a timeout for each socket using `socket.setTimeout`. If the timeout due to inactivity is reached the socket will be closed.

Maybe this will help you.

Read more about it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html)

Comment: Thank you, it seens like a good solution:) But can i not close the socket when the time is over? I just want to send the client that his time is over and a fold/check event.